# Does anyone know the FOV of hololens 2 sensors?

Tags: camera, sensors, hololens

I am beginner in hololens 2. I am trying to compare the FOV of hololens 2 sensors (such as RGB camera, depth camera, etc.). Does anyone know the FOV of hololens 2 sensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Horizontal Field of View of the RGB Camera in HoloLens2 is 64.69. To access and control RGB camera, the [Universal Windows media capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-19041) and Windows media foundation APIs can help you do it on HoloLens. More information please see:[Locatable camera](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/locatable-camera#hololens-2)

But for Depth/VLC Cameras, there is currently no official public information on them. And Depth/VLC Cameras only available on the [Research Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/research-mode) which is currently in Public Preview still plus not for usage in a commercial setting.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!